# C# - How to assign a new data table in a datagridview datasource when it already contains an initial data table

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datasource

My code works like this:

```
MyDataGridView.Datasource = initialdt
```

then I want to assign a new data table to it:

```
MyDataGridView.Datasource = newdt
```

My problem is that the datasource doesn't change even though I'm assigning a new data table to it, I've already tried making it null but still the value remains as the initial data table.

P.S. I've already researched most of related topics to my problem but still can't find answers

Comment: Try using a `BindingSource` instead. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Specify if you are using web application or windows forms.

Comment: I'm using wiindows form and btw I've already used bindingsource before but still yields the same result

Comment: Does the new datatable have the same structure?

Comment: Anyway, could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to check?

Comment: Did you debug and check the values for initialdt and newdt are they different?